# Invariance of magnetic susceptibility when rotating a tight-binding Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, model-hamiltonians, greens-functions, neutron-scattering, lindhard-theory

We know the magnetic susceptibility for a non-interacting tight-binding model has the Lindhardt form, for which I express as product of matsubara Green's functions
$$\chi^{(0)}(q,\omega)=-\beta\sum_{k,\nu,abcd} G^{ad}(k,\nu)G^{cb}(k+q,\nu+\omega) $$$abcd$ are orbital index.
Specifically, provide no SOC, the $zz-$component
$$\chi^{(0)}_{zz}=\langle S^z S^z\rangle=\frac{1}{2} [ \chi^{(0)}_{\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow}\ -\chi^{(0)}_{\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow}\ \ ]=\frac{1}{2}  \chi^{(0)}_{\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow}
$$

My question is, if we rotate the Hamiltonian to a different basis set, for example from spherical harmonics to cubic harmonics by matrix $T$, then the Green's functions are replaced as $T^\dagger GT$, and the invariance of $\chi^{(0)}$ is broke. However in principle it should be invariance since it associated with neutron scattering experiment.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just wanted to check how things are going for you with this problem? Have you figured out the answer? Have you made any progress? Are you still working on it? Please update us!